# Why does R take so much time to run auto.arima(). How can I shorten the calculation time?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, seasonality, time-complexity

I have been trying to run analysis and model a ts series of Natural Gas spot prices. With data provided by the Qandl API.

The whole analysis was working fine, however, I experiences issues with the auto.arima function.

1- If I specify the NG series as XTS, the auto.arima function does not take into account the seasonality. It's quite a bummer for Natural Gas, as the consumption of this resources is all about the time of the year.

2- If I specify the NG series as TS, the auto.arima function takes forever to calculate, and I am not even sure it can finish it. As i let it run the calculation for 20 min once, and it couldn't come with an answer. Hence, I am wondering if there is a problem with my code or my specification. 
I'm new to data science, it's my first TS project. I really love what I am doing !

Here is my code:

```
NG1= Quandl("CHRIS/CME_NG1", start_date =start, end_date =end, type =  type)$Settle
prices2returns <- function(x) diff(log(x))
spotprice2returns <- function(x,y) log(x) - log(y)
nn=300
r_NG1=xts((NG1),frequency = 300)


**tsrng= xts(r_NG1, frequency = 300)**

NG_model1= auto.arima(tsrng,trace = TRUE, test = "kpss", ic="bic")
forecast=forecast(NG_model1, h=100)
[![Forecast without seasonality][1]][1]
#############################################################
Fitting models using approximations to speed things up...

 ARIMA(2,1,2) with drift         : -1746.361
 ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         : -1735.83
 ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         : -1771.906
 ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         : -1773.598
 ARIMA(0,1,0)                    : -1744.349
 ARIMA(1,1,1) with drift         : -1764.14
 ARIMA(0,1,2) with drift         : -1765.134
 ARIMA(1,1,2) with drift         : -1755.608
 ARIMA(0,1,1)                    : -1782.117
 ARIMA(1,1,1)                    : -1772.66
 ARIMA(0,1,2)                    : -1773.653
 ARIMA(1,1,0)                    : -1780.426
 ARIMA(1,1,2)                    : -1764.128

 Now re-fitting the best model(s) without approximations...

 ARIMA(0,1,1)                    : -1785.296

 Best model: ARIMA(0,1,1)                    

Series: r_NG1 
ARIMA(0,1,1) 

Coefficients:
          ma1
      -0.0966
s.e.   0.0141

sigma^2 estimated as 0.04087:  log likelihood=901.17
AIC=-1798.34   AICc=-1798.33   BIC=-1785.3

Training set error measures:
                       ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE         ACF1
Training set 3.216548e-06 0.2021306 0.1179395 -0.0660193 2.448464 0.9986513 0.0003003316

Forecast method: ARIMA(0,1,1)

Model Information:
Series: r_NG1 
ARIMA(0,1,1) 

Coefficients:
          ma1
      -0.0966
s.e.   0.0141

sigma^2 estimated as 0.04087:  log likelihood=901.17
AIC=-1798.34   AICc=-1798.33   BIC=-1785.3

Error measures:
                       ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE         ACF1
Training set 3.216548e-06 0.2021306 0.1179395 -0.0660193 2.448464 0.9986513 0.0003003316

###############################################################

**tsrng= ts(r_NG1, frequency = 300)**

NG_model2 = auto.arima(tsrng, trace=TRUE, test="kpss", ic="aic", 
                    stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE, D=1)   
# It blocks here, and takes a lot of time to compute the model


NG_frct=forecast(NG_model4,h=100)
plot(NG_frct, include = 1500)
```

What do you suggest I do ? 
I was thinking about specifying manually the seasonal arima function, but I lack the skills to do so for now, where should I start to learn how to specify the function myself ? 
What did I do wrong in my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time series modeling with high-frequency data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29424/time-series-modeling-with-high-frequency-data) There was an ever closer related thread, but I cannot find it...

Comment: Or maybe there wasn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard. I was looking at it. I tried it, and it does a great job, however, I have 2 issues: 
- How to select the best K 
- How to forecast afterwards, the Forecast function does not work

Comment: See Rob J. Hydman's blog posts ["Forecasting weekly data"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-weekly-data/) and ["Forecasting with long seasonal periods"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now I understand. I will use the function asap !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known problem and has been discussed in Rob Hyndman's blog post ["Forecasting with long seasonal periods"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/). The problem is that the memory use is prohibitively high for seasonal periods of around 200 and more (you have 300). The solution that Hyndman proposes is to use a regression with Fourier terms and ARMA errors (the Fourier terms account for the seasonality). See the blog post above and another one, ["Forecasting weekly data"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-weekly-data/), for details.